# Topic modeling using pre-existing topics

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, text-classification, topic-modeling

I need to do topic modeling in certain number of documents in R using LDA.

I have **n** most occurring words for each of **M** topics and I want to feed this to LDA and want to get most occurring topic(out of M topics) present in each document.

In short -

**Input** - X Documents, M topics with n top words for each

**Output** - Top occurring 2 topics out of M topics in each document.

Is there any way to achieve this using already existing package in R or any other language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to achieve this with [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics.php). The command line syntax for this task is

```
bin/mallet classify-file <filename> --classifier FILE --output FILE
```

where the classifier FILE contains your pre-trained topics.

Comment: What should be the content of classifier file. Can you please suggest any tutorial for classifier based topic modeling.

Comment: @Shubham: Try `bin/mallet train-topics --help`, this should give you and overview of the different output files MALLET can produce.